# Memory Trace with Memory Contents

Tags: memory, valgrind

I'm trying to acquire a memory trace of a run of a simple program where I could see **both address and data being read/written**, e.g. `W 0x7fffffffd928 4 0xe4d829d0` which would stand for writing a 4-byte value `0xe4d829d0` to the address `0x7fffffffd928`.

There's a tool in Valgrind (Lackey tool) which only gives you the address and data length. Since Valgrind tools' documentation is quite poor, I viewed Valgrind sources but there doesn't seem to be any direct access to the data.

Another possibility seems to be Pin from Intel but after reading its documentation I haven't found anything relevant either.

This seems to be a very simple problem, however, I can't figure out or find any solution. Thanks!

Comment: did you figure it our for valgrind, too?

Comment: A full toolbox has been published recently, see the [repo on github](https://github.com/SideChannelMarvels/Tracer). Includes both PIN and Valgrind tracers. Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you for the hint! It could be what I am looking for. I assume that you use the two tracers in the paper 'Differential Computation Analysis: Hiding your White-Box Designs is Not Enough' ?

Comment: Yep, as a part of my thesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key function for PIN is `PIN_SafeCopy` which must be surrounded by `PIN_GetLock` and `PIN_ReleaseLock`. See the full functional PIN tool at [Philippe Teuwen's blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20150812030544/http://wiki.yobi.be/wiki/MoVfuscator_Writeup#Traces).